# How to save array of objects in MongoDB.in a Node.js application

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upload an Excel file to MongoDB database.

I used below NPM package manager to convert Excel data to MongoDB

```
mongoXlsx.xlsx2MongoData(path, model, function(err, data){
  console.log(data); // (This variable data has an array of objects, each object is a row in Excel.)
});
```

The image attached has the data.
Now, I want to upload this 'data' (That has an array of objects) into MongoDB. How can I do that? Please suggest.[image]

Comment: Mongodb only takes data which are in json format, are you making sure that before pushing your data to mongodb, you are converting it into correct json format ?

Comment: Please format the code. just click on edit, select the code and type ctrl-K

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the array , and insert each element of the array in a single mongoDB document :

```
for ( var counter=0 ;counter<data.length;counter++)
{
    dataBaseName.colletionName.insertOne(data[counter]);
}
```

but before that, as @zenwraight pointed out, you should convert your data into correct json format , for example `Name : 'ABC'` should become `'Name' : 'ABC'` (same goes for other fields)